# What's the best way to store, strech and display a bitmap using GDI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm not exactly a windows programming expert ;) so please excuse me if this question is trivial.

I have a window on which I want to display a bitmap. The bitmap can be either stretched to span over the whole area or it will be displayed with original aspect ratio and empty space will be filled with a solid brush.

I load the bitmap with LoadImage and display it using BitBlt. I do it on WM_ERASEBKGND, I use the DC from wparam which is a mem DC.

I was thinking of using StretchBlt instead of BitBlt when the bitmap needs to be stretched.

So my questions are:

- is it okay to store a bitmap as HBITMAP or should I use DIBSection? Which one is better performance-wise, what's the memory footprint of both solutions?
- should I always stretch the bitmap when drawing to a DC on WM_ERASEBKGND, or should I create a compatible DC (or bitmap) with a precomputed stretched bitmap and then just BitBlt it to the target DC?
- if I create a precomputed bitmap, should I immediately unload the original bitmap to save on memory?
- should I use BitBlt/StretchBlt or CopyImage?
- I read that I can also use LoadImage with desired width and height parameter, so that the loaded image is already stretched, is this solution better?

I'd be really grateful for some code examples.

**Edit:**

GDI+ solutions are welcome too. I'm interested in the best, easiest and best-performing solution for this problem.

Comment: Native GDI api is very lean for this. GDI+ is much better and easy. I would advice switch to GDI+ when it is not critical for you. Some first catch example is here http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/resizing-an-image-with-gdi-with-cpp/

Comment: If GDI+ is easier then I could use it also, but I wouldn't like to redesign the whole app. I have a dll that subclasses a window, so I only hook to WM_ERASEBKGND to display my bitmap, I thought it's better to use simpler GDI for that case.

Comment: Actually GDI+ is part of OS and Windows API since Windows 2000. One more cons to GDI that resize interpolation quality will not good as with GDI+.

Comment: @vasylz [GDI+ was introduced in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798.aspx)